# Get the closest input name after clicking on a link

Tags: jquery

I have this repeating code :

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="001" value="bla bla bla">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
            <li><a href="#" class="img-preview">Preview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="img-change">Change</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="img-delete">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How by clicking on the Change button, I can know the input name (i.e. : 001) ?

---

I tried:

```
$('.img-change').closest('input').name();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you need this

```
$(document).on('click','.img-change',function(){
   var getname = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').attr('name');
   alert (getname);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input` is not an ancestor of `.img-change`. You need to do this way:

```
$('.img-change').closest('input-group').find('input').name();
```